# Why doesn't 3d acceleration work?

Tags: 10.10, drivers, nvidia, nouveau, 3d

Hello first of all and **sorry if my english is hard to understand** hehe

I've been using Ubuntu since 9.04 and I used the 3d effects.
But since the 9.10 version, the drivers stop working. I have a Nvidia GeForce 5200fx and everytime I download and install the driver 
the resolution changes to 640x480 and I can't change it to 1024x768 again. I tried everything, even using 3d acceleration with nouveau drivers (in this case, my
resolution doesn't change, but anyway I can't use the 3d effects).
I know that my video card is very old, but is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Please specify what version of Ubuntu you're using now.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 "Maverick Merkkat"

Answer (score 2):

Nouveau does not yet have 3D accelleration for nvidia video cards. It should have it within a few months, I think. At this time, those of us with Nvidia video must use the hardware drivers to enable 3D.

Answer (score 1):

Which driver version did you install? the Ubuntu and Nvidia developer recommends nvidia-96 for legacy device.

Btw, can you show some last line your Xorg.log. You can see it in System > Adminstration > Log file Viewer.

Comment: I use the latest avaible version, I download it from the nvidia website, I don't know wich version is it

Comment: hmm...you do not use the installer from the Ubuntu,. but that's okay, no problem, I also use a driver that I downloaded directly on the Nvidia site. maybe this link can help you : http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux_display_archive.html. try do download the 96 version. http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux_display_x86_96.43.05.html or 173 version http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux_display_ia32_173.08.html

Comment: Hmm I'm trying to install the driver but I get this error: ERROR: Unable to determine the version of the kernel sources located in
'/lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/build' ...

Comment: seems nvidia installer does not find its kernel source. try to install the kernel-source, sudo apt-get install kernel-source. and probably ypu need to install build-essential, sudo apt-get install build-essential

Comment: I already installed build-essentials, but now when I try to install kernel-source it says that there's no candidate for install.
Maybe Ubuntu doesn't like me :(

Comment: the kernel source package is only meta package, not the kernel itself. try to install linux-source-2.6.32, this is hte package that containing the kernel. btw, do not be sad, the more difficult to solve, the more satisfied when you're solved it. :) and this is the reason why askubuntu.com made.

Comment: Ok, I installed that like you said, but it shows me the same error that before, do you have another idea?